# How to read and write to shared memory in different processes

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

I have two processes P1 and P2.

1. I run the P1 process and it creates a shared memory buffer of 1 Mb using mmap. I do not terminate the application (so the process still has the buffer) and get the virtual address of the buffer.
2. Now I run process P2, where I will use the virtual address of the shared memory buffer, and write some data to it (not sure if I will need to mmap it here). P2 will be terminated and P1 will be made to read data from that buffer and process it.

My current approach to this problem is to get the address from P1 and use it in P2 to write data into it. The code will be run on Linux PC.

My question is that is this possible to achieve?

Comment: The address won't necessarily be the same, you pass an address to mmap and that is occupied from the file descriptor as per the man page.  You'll need to use offsets into the memory as opposed to passing literal addresses between the processes.

Comment: @w08r and how will i calculate the offsets?

Comment: For the most trivial case, writing memory at offset 0 from the start of the mapped address will be offset 0 in both processes.  Data at offset N in P1 will be found at offset N in P2 etc.

Comment: @w08r So, in short, as long as i use the base address, there shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Maybe this will point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721209/sharing-memory-between-processes-on-linux

Comment: Is using `mmap` actually a requirement? Because portable C++ solutions like [Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess.html) make sharing memory *really* easy without even having to go into Linux specifics.